# Stack limit exceeded when trying to execute a Query in Prolog

Tags: prolog

Consider the following simple input file:

```
cites(sentence(1, 2021), article(5, law(1, 2021))).
cites(Sentence, Law) :- cites(Sentence, article(_, Law)).

topic(article(5, law(1, 2021)), labour).
topic(Document, Topic) :- cites(Document, Cited), topic(Cited, Topic).
```

it basically states that:

- the sentence n. 1 of 2021 cites article n. 5 of the law n. 1 of 2021
- and that:

  - if a sentence (or another document) cites an article of a law (or of another norm), then we infer that the sentence also cites the law
  - if a sentence cites a document, and this document is about a given topic, then we infer that the sentence as well is about that topic

However, I miss something for sure, because, when I try to execute `topic(X, Y).` or `cites(X, Y).` - after giving the expected answers - they both run into infinite recursion, e.g.

```
?- cites(X, Y).
X = sentence(1, 2021),
Y = article(5, law(1, 2021)) ;
X = sentence(1, 2021),
Y = law(1, 2021) ;
ERROR: Stack limit (1.0Gb) exceeded
ERROR:   Stack sizes: local: 1Kb, global: 0.9Gb, trail: 0Kb
ERROR:   Stack depth: 38,339,071, last-call: 100%, Choice points: 4
ERROR:   In:
ERROR:     [38,339,071] user:cites(_230034490, <compound article/2>)
ERROR:     [9] '$toplevel':toplevel_call('<garbage_collected>')
ERROR:     [8] '$toplevel':stop_backtrace('<garbage_collected>')
ERROR:     [7] '$tabling':'$wfs_call'('<garbage_collected>', '<garbage_collected>')
ERROR:     [5] '$toplevel':'$execute_goal2'('<garbage_collected>', [length:2], _230034576)
ERROR: 
ERROR: Use the --stack_limit=size[KMG] command line option or
ERROR: ?- set_prolog_flag(stack_limit, 2_147_483_648). to double the limit.
   Exception: (38,339,071) cites(_10, article(_230034404, article(_230034398, article(_230034392, article(_230034386, article(_230034380, article(_230034374, article(_230034368, article(_230034362, article(..., ...)))))))))) ?
```

From the stack trace it's clear that it is trying to unify with a recursive structure against the `article/2` functor, but I cannot tell how to prevent it.

Comment: The second clause of `cites` calls itself wrapping the given `Law` with `article(_, Law)` . It creates an infinite loop. The first clause will no longer unify the second parameter, and it will endessly apply the second clause each time with a bigger term.

Comment: @gusbro ok - got it: what solution do you propose? I came to this solution: cites(Sentence, law(Number, Year)) :- cites(Sentence, article(_, law(Number, Year))). But I wonder if there is some better way to do it.

Comment: @PiercarloSlavazza: that is exactly the solution I wanted to propose :-) What do you not like about it?

Comment: How do your other norms look?

Comment: @PiercarloSlavazza not sure if that is what you need. So `Law` can either be an `article/2` or a `law/2` ? If thats the case then maybe your proposal is right, it wil only "enter" recursion on a `law/2` but only once, then it has to be an `article`... so not sure if thats what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have already realized, the problem is the second clause.

There are several ways to fix this:

**(1) by direct pattern matching:**

```
cites(Document, law(A,B)) :- 
    cites(Document, article(_, law(A,B))).
```

**(2) by recurring to the form of the `Law` with the help of `functor/3`**

```
cites(Document, Law) :- 
    functor(Law, law, 2),
    cites(Document, article(_, Law)).
```

**(3) by defining a predicate that is true if its argument is a norm:**

```
cites(Document, Norm) :- 
    is_a_norm(Norm),
    cites(Document, article(_, Norm)).
```

`ìs_a_norm/1` can be defined in various ways, e.g.

```
is_a_norm(Norm):-     functor(Norm, law, 2).

is_a_norm(law(_,_)). % pattern matching
```

---

Option (3) with definitions of `is_a_norm` via pattern matching could be what you are looking for, since in this case you need not have several clauses for cites if you have several kinds of norms.

Example:

```
cites(Document, Norm) :- 
    is_a_norm(Norm),
    cites(Document, article(_, Norm)).

is_a_norm(law(_,_)).
is_a_norm(some_funky_other_norm(_,_,_)).
...
```

Answer (score 1):

The error:

```
Y = law(1, 2021) ;
ERROR: Stack limit (1.0Gb) exceeded
```

indicates that your query might have gone into an infinite loop. If this is the case even increasing the stack limit would not help. Tabling will also not help, since this clause:

```
cites(Sentence, Law) :- cites(Sentence, article(_, Law)).
```

Is non-well-founded. Since the second argument `article(_, Law)`of the recursive call of cites/2 is larger than the second argument `Law` in the head.

Prolog and Prolog tabling only works for definitions that are not obviously non-well-founded. You need to reformulate your problem, @tiffi suggestions help.